# DynamoDB Mapper Type Conversion with Boolean

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I have a member field that I'm having trouble converting using the DynamoDB Java Mapper.

```
@DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = MyEnumBooleanConverter.class)
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "enumMap")
private Map<MyEnum, Boolean> enumMap;
```

MyEnumBooleanConverter looks like:

```
public class MyEnumBooleanConverter implements
        DynamoDBTypeConverter<Map<String, Boolean>, Map<MyEnum, Boolean>> {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Boolean> convert(Map<MyEnum, Boolean> unconvertedMap) {
        return CollectionUtils.emptyIfNull(unconvertedMap.entrySet()).stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry.getKey().toString(), Map.Entry::getValue));
    }

    @Override
    public Map<MyEnum, Boolean> unconvert(Map<String, Boolean> convertedMap) {
        return CollectionUtils.emptyIfNull(convertedMap.entrySet()).stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
                entry -> MyEnum.valueOf(entry.getKey()), Map.Entry::getValue));
    }
}
```

The converter is serializing everything fine but when I'm doing an update, it's converting my mapping from BOOL to N and saving it that way.

Is there a way I can ensure my custom DynamoDBTypeConverter keeps the DynamoDB BOOL type? I only see the @DynamoDBTyped(DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.DynamoDBAttributeType.BOOL)
annotation for fields, but not custom converters.

I would expect that someone has created a custom converter with boolean before and run into this issue. Let me know if you can help!

Just some additional details:
Looking through source code, it looks like it's eventually using V2CompatibleBool AbstractRule, rather than the NativeBool rule.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by using DynamoDBMapperConfig with ConversionSchema V2. However, I would still like to know if there is a way to do that without changing the default conversion schema.

There are 3 ConversionSchemas in DDB, V1, V2_Compatible, and V2. The V2 by default changes all booleans to BOOL. The V2_Compatible converts them to N and is the default conversion schema. Thus, the converter was taking the BOOL and changing it to an N in the absence of the @DynamoDBTyped(DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.DynamoDBAttributeType.BOOL) annotation. Still unclear how to apply this annotation to a custom converter though.